# How to separate google map positions when zooming in?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, position

I am using google map to show multiple locations on a map.

When the map is zoomed out close by positions tend to get closer, so I want to show different maker showing position count.

when I zoom in up to a point, I would like to show the actual positions.

I have seen this implemented. I am puzzled what is the approach used to do this.

Is there a setting on google maps to automatically handle this?

Or is there a plugin for this?

Answer (score 0):

Got my info from here

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31846

The idea I think it is to go checking the zoom level _onGeoChanged, and show data accordingly to it.

```
    class GeoSelectorWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  void _onGeoChanged(CameraPosition position) {
    print("position: " + position.target.toString());
    print("zoom: " + position.zoom.toString());
    //HERE
    //if zoom>3 {show X}elseif
    //zoom>5 {show Y} 
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _controller.complete(controller);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GoogleMap(
      onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: initGeo,
        zoom: initZoom,
      ),
      onCameraMove: _onGeoChanged,
    );
  }
}
```